# How to convert log4j.xml to logback.xml?

Tags: log4j, logback

I am shifting from log4j to logback so i need to convert my log4j.xml to logback.xml

Comment: Please rewrite your question : software recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can translate it by hand back to the log4j properties format you can use [the log4j.properties to logback.xml translator](http://logback.qos.ch/translator/) on the Logback project site.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: The tool is still listed in the sidebar of the [Logback site](https://logback.qos.ch/) but it appears to be having issues right now, along with the main QoS site (the guy/company behind Logback).

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and found a better solution. First of all you will need to start from an up to date log4j.xml. Mine still had things like `category` and `priority` tags, that must be replaced respectively by `logger` and `level` in the configuration. Then remove every specific appenders like for instance `RollingFileAppender`. You will have to convert those by hand afterwards.

Then follow the instructions from [this blog](http://rpuchkovskiy.blogspot.fr/2014/11/xslt-to-convert-log4jxml-config-to.html) to convert your log4j.xml file to a logback.xml file using Xalan and an XSLT conversion filter. Since the content of this blog is rather precious for my answer, I personnaly ensured that this article can be [found in the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104132628/http://rpuchkovskiy.blogspot.com/2014/11/xslt-to-convert-log4jxml-config-to.html) just in case. Also, the article does not give the versions of the required libraries. Here are the one I used:

- serializer-2.7.1
- xalan-2.7.0
- xercesImpl-2.6.2
- xml-apis-1.3.02

And here is the command line that worked for me (executed in the same folder where all libraries and resources were:

```
java -classpath  xalan-2.7.0.jar org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN log4j.xml -XSL log4j-to-logback.xsl -OUT logback.xml
```

Now most of the work is already done. First of all I reorganized all the loggers like they were in the original log4j.xml file for easier further comparison. Then I converted the special appenders by hand. It is easier than it looks, the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) is rather clear. Here is an example (the most complex I had to deal with actually):

```
<!-- Log4J Configuration -->
<appender name="myAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/myApp.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %X{param} %-5p %m%n" />
    </layout>
       <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
              <param name="StringToMatch" value="PATTERN1" />
              <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
      </filter>
      <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
              <param name="StringToMatch" value="PATTERN2" />
              <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
      </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>


<!-- Logback configuration -->
<appender name="myAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${catalina.base}/logs/myApp.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/myApp.log.%i</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">      
        <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
            <expression>return message.contains("PATTERN1");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">      
        <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
            <expression>return message.contains("PATTERN2");</expression>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %X{param} %-5p %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

NB: If your configuration requires the use of evaluator filters like mine, you will need to declare janino and commons-compiler (same version as slf4j) in the libraries of your project